# Firebase RemoveValue

Tags: android, firebase

Estou tendando manter uma lista no firebase de id...
a intenção é quando apertar o botão seguir se não tiver o id no firebase adicionar o id e se tiver remover o id.
Eu só consigo adicionar e não consigo remover, alguém pode me ajudar?
mPost_key é o id do usário.

```
private boolean mProcessSeguindo = false;
mProcessSeguindo = true;
private String  mPost_key = null;

----    
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
----

    mProcessSeguindo = true;
    final String user_idd = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mSeguir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final DatabaseReference newComent = mDatabase.push();
            mDatabase.child(mPost_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (mProcessSeguindo) {


                       if (dataSnapshot.child(user_idd).hasChild(mPost_key)) {
                            mDatabase.child(user_idd).child(mPost_key).removeValue();
                            mProcessSeguindo = false;

                        } else {
                            mDatabase.child(user_idd).child(mPost_key).setValue("seguindo");
                            mProcessSeguindo = false;
                        }}}

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

**RESOLVIDO**

```
        private boolean mProcessSeguindo = false;

        mSeguir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mProcessSeguindo = true;
            mDatabase.child(mPost_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    final String post_cont = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();

                    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (mProcessSeguindo) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.child(user_id).child("seguindo").hasChild(currentUserId)) {
                                    mDatabase.child(user_id).child("seguindo").child(currentUserId).removeValue();
                                    mProcessSeguindo = false;
                                    mSeguir.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
                                    mSeguir.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.seguir));
                                } else {
                                    mDatabase.child(user_id).child("seguindo").child(currentUserId).child("name").setValue(post_cont);
                                    mSeguir.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                                    mSeguir.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.seguindo));
                                    mProcessSeguindo = false;}
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nesta linha `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");`

o uid procurado:

```
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

Depois você usa o método pra saber se é nulo ou não, e decido o que será feito.